# Installing request module in python 2.7 windows 10

Tags: python-2.7, python-requests

I have installed python 2.7,added the path in environment variables trying to import requests module in python IDLE.
To install requests module i am trying to use 
 `python -m pip install requests`
but i am getting error

```
Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x040C7530>, 'Connection to pypi.python.org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/requests/ 
 Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement requests (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for requests
```

please help me what can i do

Comment: looks like your pip is not able to connect to the internet. Check your internet connection once

Comment: Internet connection is working fine no issues.Please let me know what else can i check

Answer (score 0):

This answer won't tell you why you are getting that error, but suggests a workaround at the end.

Just a wild guess but perhaps the error is caused by not having the correct version of pip?

[Python : ImportError: No module named requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37059323/python-importerror-no-module-named-requests)